Explanation on $\S 3.18$ on Lectures on von Neumann Algebras
I am reading $\S3.18$ from the book Lectures on von Neumann Algebras, Stratila and Zsido. I didn't understand this section completely.
What I understood is following:

The following is a $*$-isomorphism.
$$
\mathscr{M}\ni x\mapsto \tilde{x}\in \mathscr{M}\overline{\otimes}\mathscr{C}(\mathscr{K})
$$

For $e_i:=u_iu_i^*$, we get for all $j, k \in I$
$$
(e_i)_{j,k} =u_j^*(e_i)u_k= \begin{cases}
1_{\mathscr{H}} \text{ if } j=k = i \\
0 \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
thus $e_i \in \text{Mat}_{\gamma}(\mathscr{C}(\mathscr{H}))=\mathscr{C}(\mathscr{H})\overline{\otimes}\mathscr{B}(\mathscr{K})$.

For $x \in \mathscr{M}$ and $j, k \in I$ we have:
$$
(u_ixu_i^*)_{j,k} =u_j^*(u_ixu_i^*)u_k= \begin{cases}
x \text{ if } j=k = i \\
0 \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
thus $u_ixu_i^*\in \text{Mat}_{\gamma}(\mathscr{M})=\mathscr{M}\overline{\otimes}\mathscr{B}(\mathscr{K})$ and hence the following is a $*$-isomorphism:
$$
\mathscr{M}\ni x \mapsto u_ixu_i^*|_{\mathscr{H}_i}\in \left(\mathscr{M}\overline{\otimes} \mathscr{B}(\mathscr{K})\right)_{e_i}
$$


What I didn't understand are:
Q1. The authors mentioned that the map in $3$ above is also a $*$-isomorphism from $\mathscr{M}$ onto $\left(\mathscr{M}\overline{\otimes} \mathscr{C}(\mathscr{K})\right)_{e_i}$. How? as seen in $3$, the matrix of $u_ixu_i^*$ implies that it may not necessarily lie in $\mathscr{M}\overline{\otimes} \mathscr{C}(\mathscr{K})=\tilde{\mathscr{M}}_\gamma$ (Prop 3.17(i)).
Q2. The authors also wrote that $\left(\mathscr{M}\overline{\otimes} \mathscr{B}(\mathscr{K})\right)_{e_i}=\left(\mathscr{M}\overline{\otimes} \mathscr{C}(\mathscr{K})\right)_{e_i}$. Why?
Q3. And finally what exactly did they mean in the last paragraph which goes like this:

Thus, the passage from $\mathscr{M}$ to $\mathscr{M}\overline{\otimes} \mathscr{B}(\mathscr{K})$ (resp., to $\mathscr{M}\overline{\otimes} \mathscr{C}(\mathscr{K})$) and the passage from a von Neumann algebra to a reduced algebra (resp., to an induced algebra) are reciprocal operations, whereas the $*$-isomorphism reciprocal to an amplification is an induction.

Thank you.
